# How to check file creation date with github api

Tags: git, github, github-api

I'm using the github api to [grab the contents of files](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents), but I'd like to also see when the files were created. Is there a way to get that information with the github api?

Comment: I suspect the answer is "not easily", because that's not information that git tracks per file.  You could [iterate over commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/) in the repository, and for each commit [see if the file exists](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/), and then for the earliest commit you find that contains the file, consider the commit date to be the "creation date".

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194241/get-when-the-file-was-last-updated-from-a-github-repository

Answer (score 2):

The `commits` endpoint can be filtered via the [`path` parameter](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#parameters), so that it only returns commits that touch the given path. Unless you want to get tricky and make multiple requests to follow file moves/renames, I'd just use the commit date of the furthest commit returned.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not store *file* creation dates (in a significant sense, Git's files don't *have* creation dates).  You may be able to get something of use to you anyway, but GitHub's interface is leading you in the wrong direction.

If you examine the ["create a file" operation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) closely enough, and are familiar with Git, you will realize that it does not really create a file at all: instead, it makes a new *commit*.  This is why it needs a commit message, and allows an author and committer.

What this means is that you must find a commit that contains the file, and then [retrieve the information about that commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit).  The problem here is twofold:

- *finding a commit that contains the file*, and
- *defining what you mean by "created"*.

To find a commit, you need a commit hash (SHA-1 ID).  The main place to get a commit hash is from a commit.  So you'll need a commit hash in order to find a commit hash.  This is, of course, a problem.

To break the deadlock here, you must start by [looking up a reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/).  A reference is simply a name that is paired with a Git object hash—often, but not always, a *commit* object hash.  You then use that reference to locate a commit: if the reference points directly to a commit, you're there; if it points to a tag (an annotated tag object), you read the tag object, which contains another hash ID.  Keep reading these objects until you arrive at something that is *not* a tag.  If that's a commit, you've succeeded.  If it's a tree or a blob, the tag does not lead to a commit in the first place and probably is not interesting to you.

The reference you want to start with is the same reference you have been using to retrieve the file.

Now that you *do* have a commit ID and can retrieve the commit, it is time to see if the file in question even exists in that commit.  Presumably it *does* exist that particular commit, since you have been retrieving the file.  But the file may not have been *created* in that commit: it may simply have been carried over from a previous commit.

If, by "created", you mean "when was the *most recent commit* created", you can stop here: get the commit and use the author date and/or committer date.  If, however, you mean "find me a commit where in some *previous* commit, the file *does not* exist", you must do much more work.  You must now [retrieve the *tree object* associated with each commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/), in order to see whether some file `$path` such as `foo/bar.txt` exists in *that particular commit* (the other API that you have been using only retrieves files from the *tip-most* commit on a given reference).

Note that each commit can have *more than one parent*.  This occurs for merge commits.  Most such commits have exactly two parents, but any number above 1 is possible.  When looking at a merge commit that contains some file path `$path`, each of its (multiple) parents may also have file `$path` or lack file `$path`.  This is where "defining what you mean by created" becomes particularly difficult.

- For a commit with *no* parents (a root commit), clearly file `foo/bar.txt` is "created" here if it exists.
- For a commit with *one* parent, clearly file `foo/bar.txt` is "created" if `foo/bar.txt` exists in this commit, but not in this commit's parent.
- For a commit with *two or more* parents, clearly file `foo/bar.txt` is "created" if `foo/bar.txt` exists in this commit, but not in *any* of its parents.
- But for a commit with two or more parents, if `foo/bar.txt` exists in this commit and *some but not all* parents, is the file "created"?

Once you solve this problem, you are ready to go, with a few minor caveats.  First, the "get a tree" API interface imposes limits, so for bigger trees, you must clone the repository.  Second, the work involved in doing this is, in general, the *same* as cloning the repository: you are basically re-implementing Git.  You might as well just use Git.

Comment: "You might as well just use Git" seems to be the point of your whole answer, but using git might not be an option. Consider a single page app that's just using the GitHub api, for example.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart: in which case, you must reimplement big chunks of Git, and forego getting an answer for trees whose size exceeds the GitHub API. If that's what you want, go for it! :-) Seriously, though, the "filter by commits that affect the file" is probably a good approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem, and after reading ansers above, and after some digering. I found a trick way todo.

When you browse a repo, open chrome dev panel -> network tab. Then select a new folder to browse. There should be a xhr request like `xxxx/file-list/xxxx`, so this request can also be re-issueed from our code, and parse the response to extract each file item last modified date.

I know it's not a good way, but maybe can help.