# Get when the file was last updated from a Github repository

Tags: github, github-api

I'm able to get the file contents (and if it's a folder, I'm able to get the list of files) by [using the GitHub v3 API.](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents)
Example:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/[Owner]/[Repository]/contents/[Folder]
```

But how can I know when the file was last updated? Is there an API for that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you know the exact file path, you can use [list commits on repository API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) specifying a `path` which only includes commits with this specific file path and then extract the most recent commit (the most recent is the first one) :

#### Using Rest API v3

https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/speed-test-lib/commits?path=jspeedtest%2Fbuild.gradle&page=1&per_page=1

Using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/speed-test-lib/commits?path=jspeedtest%2Fbuild.gradle&page=1&per_page=1" | \
     jq -r '.[0].commit.committer.date'
```

#### Using GraphqQL API v4

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "bertrandmartel", name: "speed-test-lib") {
    ref(qualifiedName: "refs/heads/master") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 1, path: "jspeedtest/build.gradle") {
            edges {
              node {
                committedDate
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?payload=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22speed-test-lib%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ref(qualifiedName%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%201%2C%20path%3A%20%22jspeedtest%2Fbuild.gradle%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20committedDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN" \
     -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{ repository(owner: \"bertrandmartel\", name: \"speed-test-lib\") { ref(qualifiedName: \"refs/heads/master\") { target { ... on Commit { history(first: 1, path: \"jspeedtest/build.gradle\") { edges { node { committedDate } } } } } } } }"
         }' https://api.github.com/graphql | \
     jq -r '.data.repository.ref.target.history.edges[0].node.committedDate'
```

Comment: I was just writing this, of course, less detailed :)

Comment: We can use `&page=1&per_page=1` to avoid loading all commits, if using REST API v3.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find GraphQL very unintuitive

Answer (score 11):

#### Using Python

pip install PyGithub

```
from github import Github
g = Github()
repo = g.get_repo("datasets/population")
print(repo.name)
commits = repo.get_commits(path='data/population.csv')
print(commits.totalCount)
if commits.totalCount:
    print(commits[0].commit.committer.date)
```

Output:

```
population
5
2020-04-14 15:09:26
```

https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub

Comment: There also appears to be a `last_modified` field on the contents objects, eg, 

`contents = repo.get_contents('data/population.csv')`
`print(contents.last_modified)`

And though it appears the same date, it is also a string :-(

Answer (score 3):

That would be surprising, considering git does not [store file timestamps (and other metadata like permissions and ownership)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284229/6309), for reasons [I detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964508/6309).

So that information is not present on the remote repository side (here GitHub) either.

Comment: Yes, but GitHub knows when the file was last updated (for example, it shows the last commit if you open the file).

Comment: That's why I found it strange that the timestamp was missing. :)

Comment: The commit date has nothing to do with the for last modifications timestamp

Comment: Oh, I'm wrong then. But I don't understand why, could you elaborate?

Comment: The link I mention in my answer does elaborate. The other answer just retrieve when a copy has been done

Answer (score 0):

You can actually determine what you want using the request you specifically mentioned.

Note that all dates/times below are under GMT (of course).

> Copy & paste the following command to find the last modified date and time of Folder/File in repository ForStackExchange by user YenForYang:
>
> ```
> \curl -sIA. --ignore-content-length  \
>      -H"If-Modified-Since: Sun May 01 00:00:00 9999" \
>      "https://api.github.com/repos/YenForYang/ForStackExchange/contents/Folder/File?ref=branch" \
> | \grep -m1 -oP "(?<=Last-Modified: )[ADFJMNOSTWa-eghilnoprtuvy0-9:, ]{25}" \
> ```
>
> (If Perl regex isn't available, you can `... | grep -F -m1 "Last-Modified:"`)

---

> The above command should return (GMT): `Thu, 27 Dec 2018 11:01:26`
>   (or later, if I update the file for some reason)

---

Note that if the `ref` parameter is unspecified, `ref=master`.

---

And if you can't copy and paste, and don't care about the API rate limits, you might opt for the shorter:

```
\curl -sIL "api.github.com/repos/yenforyang/forstackexchange/contents/Folder/File?ref=branch" | \grep "^Las"
```

And if ya don't have `grep` on Windows just use `find "Last-Modified: "` instead (doubles quotes are necessary).

And if you don't have curl on Windows (download it...or) use Powershell

```
(iwr -me HEAD -usebasic "https://api.github.com/repos/yenforyang/forstackexchange/contents/Folder/File?ref=branch").Headers."Last-Modified"
```

Comment: This is a great advice. One caveat though: this request results in time of latest commit for ENTIRE folder / repo, not for individual file specified. I failed to find any docs explaining reasons for that.

Answer (score -1):

When you run a public repository with GitHub Pages and want to let your visitors know the history of a page, you can simply put the hyperlink to the `https://github.com/<user>/<user>.github.io/commits/main/<path-to-file>` for that page on that page.