# Get last commit date of a file with github api

Tags: github, github-api

The normal `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path` doesn't contain any information about date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get when the file was last updated from a Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194241/get-when-the-file-was-last-updated-from-a-github-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

1. In order to find the date of specific file look here - https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?path=PATH_TO_FILE

you can see here the date of the commit which is the date when the file uploaded to git.

2. check this path - https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits

inside you can see both commit date and the files of the commit

[image]

Comment: correct me if I was wrong, but I can't see any files of each commit. OFC your could further request a specific commit. but hard to know which commit involves a specific file. Unless brute force.

Comment: look at my edit, it worked great for me

Comment: yes, the first api you provided will do.