# How to implement a "last updated" indicator on a website sourced by a private GitHub repo?

Tags: javascript, html, github

I am trying to find a way to add a indicator of when the last push or update to any file in the repository was (i.e. `Last Updated May 9, 2023`), but I do not know how!

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204589/21358321) but it returned with a 404 saying that the repo/file couldn't be found.

Comment: Is your website based on GH pages?

Comment: No, it feeds to Netlify to be deployed. @SilviuBurcea

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting 404 Not found is probably because the repository is not publicly available. I don't think there is any quick solution to your use case. I'd use a template/placeholder in your views and during the build time you can use `git` to extract last modified date for your files and apply that to your placeholders inside the views.